# Change parameters inside a "data-parameters" attribute

Tags: jquery, json

Ok, so I have been looking around, but have not had found a definite answer. So, I have an HTML tag as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-parameters='{"uploadZone":0,"left":27,"top":225,"degree":0,"price":0,"replace":"togglePhone","originX":"left","originY":"top","fill":"#166fc4","opacity":1,"removable":0,"draggable":0,"rotatable":0,"resizable":0,"zChangeable":0,"topped":0,"autoSelect":0,"boundingBoxMode":"inside","fontFamily":"Open Sans","fontWeight":"normal","fontStyle":"normal","textDecoration":"normal","textAlign":"left","fontSize":16,"maxLength":0,"maxLines":0,"lineHeight":1,"strokeWidth":1,"editable":0,"curvable":0,"curved":0,"curveSpacing":10,"curveRadius":80,"curveReverse":0,"textBox":0,"customAdds": {}}' name="toggle_element" class="toggle-element" />
```

This is to be used with a plugin called "fabric.js". Now, my aim is just to manipulate the "top" parameter of that attribute. I am calling the parameters using:

```
var getParameters = $(this).data('parameters');
```

I have tried to change the top value as such:

```
$(document).on("change", ".toggle-element", function() {

    var getParameters = $(this).data('parameters');

    getParameters.top = 10;
    alert( getParameters.top );

});
```

The alert shows the correct value I posted, but for some reason, on the canvas, it is still defaulting to 225(as the sample I posted above). Is what I am trying to do possible, of am I just doing it wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

******** EDIT ********

Thanks to empiric's and Kostas Pelelis' responses, I was able to figure this out. So, what I was missing was to set the parameters back in once I did the change. So, the code would be:

```
$(document).on("change", ".toggle-element", function() {

   var getParameters = $(this).data('parameters');

   getParameters.top = 10;

   $(this).data('parameters', getParameters);

});
```

That added the new parameter that I needed and worked as expected. I even tried with manipulating some other parameters I had, and that worked as well. So basically, all I needed to do was to change the parameter value and then re-add the parameters values. This will update to the values I specified above. Now, when I first tried the code above, I made the mistake of referencing the getParameters variable correctly. So just make sure you specified very well which element you are manipulating.

Comment: Have worked on fabric.js but I guess you have to re-load fabric.js for it to render the updated value. Have a look at the docs and see if there an event like onChange or load() and fire it once you change the top value. Your code looks fine to me

Comment: after doing `getParameters.top = 10;` you have to set the data-attribute again. Side note: the `.data()` function will not update the dom itself.

Comment: Thanks both for your response. @empiric: what to dyou mean set the data-attribute again? Do you mean like using .data('parameters', newValue)?

Comment: @R.Rodriguez exactly, you could also try `$(this).attr('data-parameters');` and `$(this).attr('data-parameters', getParameters);`  instead.

Comment: @empiric Thanks for the suggestion, that actually worked. Let me edit my question to reflect it. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

I have never used fabricjs but I will answer from the jQuery perspective. As you can see [here](https://api.jquery.com/data/) data method when used with only one parameter **returns a reference** of the selected data store. So if you change something on this data, the change will not be reflected on the actual object.

EDIT: .data() actually returns a reference of the object.

What you can do is

```
$(document).on("change", ".toggle-element", function() {

    var getParameters = $(this).data('parameters');

    getParameters.top = 10;
    $(this).data('parameters', getParameters)
    alert( getParameters.top );

});
```

And this will assign the modified copy of the object, to the actual.

Comment: Hmmmm, I tried that, but it still uses the default parameter rather than the one I assign. Could be something with the plugin rather than the jQuery function itself. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Your code actually worked lol I was calling the alert before the new data was inserted. That is why it was not working before. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you mean. And example code snippet would be helpful. After setting a fabricjs object with new values you need to take your fabric canvas instance object and call `renderAll()` for the canvas to update.

Below is an example where I add a circle with some default values and then change the top offset to a new number. Only when you call `renderAll()` does the circle update it's position.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('t');

// set the circle to be at 100 from the top
var circle = new fabric.Circle({ radius: 20, fill: 'green', left: 100, top: 100 });
canvas.add(circle);

// now set the circle to be 10 from the top
circle.top = 10;

// circle will not change from 100 to 10 untill we tell the canvas to render again.
canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
canvas {
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.js"></script>

<canvas id="t" height="200" width="500">
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. Well, is not that I am trying to create a new object, but that I am trying to edit an existing one. I was able to gather the parameters of each object that I am inserting on the canvas, but what I want to do is edit those parameters once I have them at hand.